# Why is setInterval not letting my other functions run?

Tags: javascript

```js
let paddleWidth = 100;
let paddleHeight = 25;
let paddlePositionX = 200
let paddlePositionY = 200

let ballPositionX = canvas.width /2; //ball position on x
let ballPositionY = canvas.height -150; //ball position on y
let dx = 5; //shift along x
let dy = 5; //shift along y

function drawPaddle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(paddlePositionX, paddlePositionY, paddlePositionY, paddleHeight);
    ctx.rect(200, 200, 100,25)
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
drawPaddle()

function drawBall(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ballPositionX, ballPositionY, 15, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    ballPositionX += dx;
    ballPositionY += dy;

    if(ballPositionX >= canvas.width || ballPositionX + dx < 0){
        dx = -dx;
    } 
    if(ballPositionY + dy > canvas.height || ballPositionY + dy < 0) {
        dy = -dy;
    }
}
setInterval(drawBall, 10)
```

I have two functions, one moving a ball randomly and one is supposed to be a paddle on the screen, now in order to move the ball I am calling drawBall with setInterval. The problem is my paddle does not show on screen and if I comment out the setinterval it shows on screen but my ball disappears.

Comment: Probably because `drawBall` clears the entire canvas each time with `ctx.clearRect`

Comment: canvas is used to produce still images, you would benefit from doing this in SVG

Comment: that makes sense, any idea how to change it?

Comment: @kerolosaziz first of all you have to move your clear Rect before any draws happens i.e. before drawing the paddle. For example you can combine your two functions in one or create another function that call `drawBall` and `drawPaddle` in the right order. For example   `function draw() { drawBall(); drawPaddle(); }` and then call it inside `SetInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `drawBall` method starts by clearing the canvas, so after you have drawn your paddle, the interval will clear it 10ms later. Fix this by removing the `clearRect` call from your `drawBall` function and re-drawing the paddle in every loop:

```
setInterval(() => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawPaddle();
    drawBall();
}, 10)
```